# Custom field called instead of the default field 'name' in m2o field in odoo

Tags: odoo-10, many-to-one

There is a field name partner_id in model mail.channel.partner. I want that the partner_id return "Joestar" instead of it's full name 'Joseph joestar'. This should be apply only on this model .

How can I modify the partner_id(m2o) so that it will return only the last string. The goal of this is to hide the full name of the users/partners that's why I need the last string only.

The goal is when we interact to our customer through our site, we don't want to reveal our full name instead, we want to display only the last name.

In the image below, The encircled data is the name I want to modify to last name instead of full name.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7sPG.jpg)

Comment: Self.partner_id.name.split()[-1] something like that?

Comment: If you could be more specified and targeted in your question, people can help you much more quicker. Adding more clearer tags also help your audience to identify the context

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Marychan**,

Please Override **name_get** method that'll already define in **res.partner** model like this:

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for rec in self:
        result.append((rec.id, "%s" % (rec.name.strip().split()[-1])))
    return result
```

That will give you only last word of name.

If you want to check the url for you model:-

```
from openerp import http
print http.request.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.base.url') # BASE URL
print http.request.httprequest 
print http.request.httprequest.full_path
```

**Check before stripping and spliting**